# Manually send mass email based on filter criteria - Sharepoint, Flow

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am trying to setup a manual flow that can send out a mass email.

1. Manually trigger an email (In the below photo I show when a new item is created, however I prefer to run this manually when I want to, if possible)
2. Send out one mass reminder email. (BCC). Custom message, maybe include a few columns from List "population".
3. Email addresses are stored in  List "population", Column "c_Email"
4. Also as a condition I would like to only send to emails in List X where Column "Submitted" is blank.

Can anyone help with this?

Here is what I'm trying:
[image]
[image]